# how do I ensure that the vertical lines show in the gray cells of my table?

Tags: tables

how do I ensure that the vertical lines show in the gray cells of my table?

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
    \normalsize
    \doublespacing
    \centering
        \caption{Interaction between \emph{Import Industry} and \emph{Neutral Sentiment}.}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
        & DV=\emph{Bad Self Impact} &  DV=\emph{Bad US Impact} &  DV=\emph{Tariff Support}\\ \hline
    \emph{Import Industry} &  0.119  & 0.002  & 0.250  \\
     & (0.342)   & (0.985) & (0.011)\\  \hline
    \emph{Neutral Sentiment} & 0.045 & -0.008 & -0.064 \\
     & (0.688) &  (0.942) & (0.481)\\ \hline
     \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}\emph{Import Industry*} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}0.470 & \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}0.500 & 0.267\\
     \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}\emph{Neutral Sentiment} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}{0.024} & \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}{0.014} & 0.130\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}\\
    \end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In a simple article all the vertical lines are showed in this table. It should be a  problem of your viewer. Try to zoom or print the PDF.

Comment: You're right - once I printed the PDF it worked fine. Thank you!